# Restrict heading level in Gutenberg block `core/heading`

Tags: block-editor

I'm building a simple Gutenberg Block that lets the user create just headlines and lists. I've got a solution, but the user can select any heading level she or he wants to.

How I can I restrict the `core/heading` block to e.g. heading level `H4`?

The crucial part in my `edit.js` is this:

```
return (
    <div {...blockProps}>
        <InnerBlocks
            onChange = { onChangeContent }
            allowedBlocks={ ['core/list', 'core/heading'] }
        />
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the allowed blocks are entered as strings there is no way to add parameters to them. You would have to make your own component for each heading type.